# How to replace part of tensorflow codes with a saved model

Tags: session, tensorflow, graph, save, restore

I was wondering if someone can show me how to replace part of a big model with an (already) saved small model in Tensorflow. Precisely, what I want is, in the below, to make the f(x) with y=g(x) in part. The y=g(x) is the already trained, saved model, and I wanted to train f(x) without chaining g(x).

```
def f(x):
    ....
    y = g(x)
    z = tf.matmul(y, w) + b
    return z
```

And I will declare the f(x) twice like

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    z1 = f(x1)
with tf.variable_scope("bar", reuse=True):
    z2 = f(x2)
```

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like `y = tf.stop_gradient(g(x))` and load the weights of g from a checkpoint by creating your own saver and passing the list of g's variables to it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am sure that will work in a simple case. But I forgot to mention that I have to declare f(x) twice (like I added in the question later). In my case, I couldn't figure out how to handle restoring variables of g(x) within f(x) that is to declare twice.

Comment: In your case you're not reusing the variables of g because they are created in a different variable scope. To be able to "pull out" all variables of g I recommend you first create g outside of f and keep its variable scope around (`x = tf.variable_scope("g"); with x: ...` so you can later do `with tf.variable_scope(x, reuse=True)` to reenter the same scope with the same variables.